# Connect trough Cygwin without being asked for password

Tags: ssh, cygwin, sshd, ssh-keys

I'm trying to connect to a remote machine using Cygwin,
the connection is successful problem is that it always asks me for the password.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" user@machine.net 'echo test'
```

Do you know How I can login to remote server using Cygwin without password getting asked?

***BTW -*** I tried to put the private key from the remote machine on the Cygwin machine, Added the remote machine to the **known_host** file

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to put the private key from the remote machine on the Cygwin machine,

The private key isn't *automatically* useful; you also need to add its corresponding *public* key (usually the id_rsa.pub file) to the remote machine's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

In other words, you need to explicitly tell the remote machine "this private key is acceptable".

> Added the remote machine to the known_host file

That has nothing to do with passwords, does it? `known_hosts` is about authenticating the *server* to user, not the user to server.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply, So in my private user .ssh folder (C:\Users\Private_user\.ssh) I should have:  id_rsa (the private key from client/remote machine) , known_hosts , authorized_keys (With the public key from client/remote machine in it )?
is that enough for "silent" login? and if I'm using CYGWIN as I mentioned should I put this .ssh folder inside: C:\cygwin64\home\Private_user\.ssh  ?

Comment: On the client, you need the `id_rsa` file (and optionally its corresponding `id_rsa.pub`). On the server, you don't need _any_ private keys – only `authorized_keys` with a copy of the public key. (I'm not sure how Cygwin paths translate to Windows paths, but you can just run a Cygwin shell and access `~/.ssh/` from there.)

Comment: mmm....I did as you said, for some reason it keeps asking me for the password. trying to access vice versa from the WINDOWS to the LINUX it doesn't ask me for any password.